# UITableViewRowAnimationBottom doesn't work for last row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I've come across a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160796/inserting-row-to-end-of-table-with-uitableviewrowanimationbottom-doesnt-animate, though no answers have been given. His code was also a little different than mine.

I have an extremely simple example, built from the Navigation application template.

```
NSMutableArray *items;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    items = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addItem)] autorelease];
}

- (void)addItem{
    [items insertObject:@"new" atIndex:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return items.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [items removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    }   
}
```

The problem is, when I either insert or delete the very last row in the table, the animation doesn't work at all; the row just appears or disappears instantly. This only happens with UITableViewRowAnimationBottom, but that's the animation that makes the most sense for creating or deleting table cells in this way. Is this a bug in Apple's framework? Or does it do this on purpose? Would it make sense to add an extra cell to the count, and then setup this cell so that it looks like it's not there at all, just to get around this behavior?

Comment: If it's the last cell, I would try UITableViewRowAnimationTop or UITableViewRowAnimationFade. UITableViewRowAnimationBottom slides the cell to the bottom doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, with UITableViewRowAnimationBottom new cell is added 'as it is', without animation, and all rows below it are animated with sliding. So, if there is no any rows below, there will be no animation.

Comment: +1.  If you really need an animation for the last row just use something like `UITableViewRowAnimationFade`.

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to animate row (dis)appearance, works a charm

```
if (oldRowCount < rowCount)
{
    // insert
    NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    while (oldRowCount < rowCount)
    {
        [indexPaths addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: oldRowCount inSection: section]];
        oldRowCount = oldRowCount + 1;
    }
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
else if (oldRowCount > rowCount)
{
    // remove
    NSMutableArray* indexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    while (rowCount < oldRowCount)
    {
        [indexPaths addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: rowCount inSection: section]];
        rowCount = rowCount + 1;
    }
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: indexPaths withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for... I'm trying to use UITableViewRowAnimationBottom, because that's what looks right for adding or deleting a row in this way. Using Top just looks kind of strange for this purpose, plus the code I already have works just fine with Top, except the way the animation looks.